# Disable autocorrect / autocompletion in content editable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, script#

I m developing a cross-browser application in Script#.
I m using a contenteditable div, where user can add text. But i dont want the auto correct/ auto completion feature to change the user text.

Plz tell me how can i disable this feature.
It should work on all platforms. ( iOS, Android, Windows)

I have tried autocorrect="off";
autocomplete="off"

but nothing is working. plz help....

Comment: I think the auto correct features (I assume on phones, tablets etc) are part of the keyboard, and therefore just part of the OS / App. Unless that can read an attribute of the text box then I can't see how it can be disabled sadly.

Comment: Is there a way to disable the keyboard's autocorrection feature through code.

Comment: Your code can't access the keyboard hardware / software, or any part of the OS, so no way directly.

Comment: This sounds more like an HTML5/JS problem than S#. In S#, you will simply need to add the appropriate attribute to the div.

Answer (score 12):

What you can do is to use the attribute [`spellcheck=false`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#spelling-and-grammar-checking). This is (in HTML5 CR) the defined way to disable “checking of spelling and grammar of editable text”. The default value of this element is browser-dependent, and the value may depend on element. E.g., in Chrome, the default is `spellcheck=true` for an element that has been made editable using the `contenteditable` attribute.

However, this affects (at most) only what happens in the browser. Software external to the browser, such as a system’s keyboard reading routines, are probably immune to anything you say in HTML.

Comment: It would be nice if they would check... SwiftKey will remove auto correct on password fields for example, so perhaps something that's being adopted...?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the correct attributes, but I'm not positive if they are expected to work with  contenteditable (they are definitely supported for  and  tags). Current iOS versions(at least v6.1 and up) will currently support those attributes, however there is a bug in Chrome for Android not respecting these HTML 5 attributes. It appears to just recently have been fixed and hopefully should be released in an update soon.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=303883&q=autocorrect&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Also feel free to Star the issue to help boost the ranking...